# Can I select-all and count-all from a union in a single MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, count, union

I have a `SELECT` statement that returns entries from multiple tables. Here's a schematic:

```
select * from `tbl1` where `cond1`='something2'
UNION ALL
select * from `tbl2` where `cond2`='something2'
UNION ALL
-- etc
select * from `tblN` where `condN`='somethingN'
ORDER BY `sortColumn` ASC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

I also need to know the total count of all rows. So I can do:

```
SELECT count(*) as cntAll FROM(
    select * from `tbl1` where `cond1`='something2'
    UNION ALL
    select * from `tbl2` where `cond2`='something2'
    UNION ALL
    -- etc
    select * from `tblN` where `condN`='somethingN'
) as x;
```

This also works fine.

But can I combine the two into one statement?

If I try this, it simply returns one row:

```
SELECT *, count(*) as cntAll FROM(
    select * from `tbl1` where `cond1`='something2'
    UNION ALL
    select * from `tbl2` where `cond2`='something2'
    UNION ALL
    -- etc
    select * from `tblN` where `condN`='somethingN'
    ORDER BY `sortColumn` ASC
    LIMIT 0, 15
) as x;
```

PS. I'm using MySQL `v.5.7.28`

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Comment: @forpas sorry, I keep forgetting to add it. Edited my question.

Comment: @P.Salmon the same here. I do not have anything to `group by`. The `id` field in each table is `autoincrement int` but they may overlap. If there was some way to add an auto-incremented value into each `SELECT` statement in my union, I'd be able to group by it. But I don't know how. Otherwise there's no absolutely unique column in each of those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+------+
| ID   | userid | FNAME  | sname  | email  | dob        | IX   |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+------+
|    1 |      1 | fname1 | sname1 | email1 | 2000-01-01 |    6 |
|    2 |      2 | fname2 | sname2 | email2 | 2000-01-01 |    5 |
|    3 |      3 | fname3 | sname3 | email3 | 2000-01-01 |    4 |
|    4 |      4 | fname4 | sname4 | email4 | 2000-01-01 |    3 |
|    5 |      5 | fname5 | sname5 | email5 | 2000-01-01 |    2 |
|    6 |      6 | fname6 | sname6 | email6 | 2000-01-01 |    1 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+------+
6 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Then you could read the union twice once to get the rows an secondly to get the count using a cross join

```
select a.* , b.cnt
from 
(select * from users t1
union all
select * from users t2
union all
select * from users t3
order by id limit 0,15
) a
cross join
(
select count(*)  cnt
from
(
select * from users t1
union all
select * from users t2
union all
select * from users t3
order by id limit 0,15
) s
) b;

+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+------+-----+
| ID   | userid | FNAME  | sname  | email  | dob        | IX   | cnt |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+------+-----+
|    1 |      1 | fname1 | sname1 | email1 | 2000-01-01 |    6 |  15 |
|    1 |      1 | fname1 | sname1 | email1 | 2000-01-01 |    6 |  15 |
|    1 |      1 | fname1 | sname1 | email1 | 2000-01-01 |    6 |  15 |
|    2 |      2 | fname2 | sname2 | email2 | 2000-01-01 |    5 |  15 |
|    2 |      2 | fname2 | sname2 | email2 | 2000-01-01 |    5 |  15 |
|    2 |      2 | fname2 | sname2 | email2 | 2000-01-01 |    5 |  15 |
|    3 |      3 | fname3 | sname3 | email3 | 2000-01-01 |    4 |  15 |
|    3 |      3 | fname3 | sname3 | email3 | 2000-01-01 |    4 |  15 |
|    3 |      3 | fname3 | sname3 | email3 | 2000-01-01 |    4 |  15 |
|    4 |      4 | fname4 | sname4 | email4 | 2000-01-01 |    3 |  15 |
|    4 |      4 | fname4 | sname4 | email4 | 2000-01-01 |    3 |  15 |
|    4 |      4 | fname4 | sname4 | email4 | 2000-01-01 |    3 |  15 |
|    5 |      5 | fname5 | sname5 | email5 | 2000-01-01 |    2 |  15 |
|    5 |      5 | fname5 | sname5 | email5 | 2000-01-01 |    2 |  15 |
|    5 |      5 | fname5 | sname5 | email5 | 2000-01-01 |    2 |  15 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------------+------+-----+
15 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Comment: Hold on, I'm trying to follow you. If I do what you suggest, wouldn't I get duplicate rows? And also have to run my (inner union) query twice? (That's what I'm trying to avoid.)

Comment: Duplicate rows - maybe it would help if you added sample data, and yes you have to run the union query twice.

Comment: OK. I see. Thanks for the idea.